# Recommended reading on advanced graph theory?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm looking for books on advanced graph theory. What would you recommend?

Relevant topics:
  - coloring theory
  - min cut
  - traveling salesman problem

Comment: how is advanced graph different from regular graph?

Comment: example : coloring graph , TSP , min cost flow .....

Comment: I want a ruby encrusted pony. Apparently, Santa did not know this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google "MAA Reviews" which is a book review site and once there search for "graph".  You will find LOTS of books reviewed there.  If that is too shotgun an approach you might post a more specific question.

ADDED LATER

The MAA site is for mathematicians.  From your more specific question I suspect you want something more basic and applied than many of the books there.  Among those they review are this basic and relatively inexpensive text

A Beginner's Guide to Graph Theory
W. D. Wallis

and this huge reference book which is reasonably priced for its size

Graph Theory and Its Applications
Jonathan L. Gross and Jay Yellen